# How do you put a cluster disk in maintenance mode in Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, iscsi, failovercluster, windows-cluster

Background: I have created a test 2-node Server 2012 R2 cluster, with an iSCSI cluster disk. I want to format a new partition on the disk. When I try to format the new partition, it says the disk must be in cluster maintenance mode.

I cannot find any option in the Failover Cluster Manager GUI to put a cluster disk into maintenance mode.

I have tried using PowerShell, running `Suspend-ClusterResource -Name "<cluster disk name"`, but get the error message "The cluster request is not valid for this object".

Answer (score 1):

First install the [update mentioned here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2937630) then I would recommend reading up on the actual functions of cluster maintenance in [this article](http://www.youdidwhatwithtsql.com/disk-maintenance-mode-failover-cluster/1713/).

Good luck!

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/39b963ad-1841-41e7-b1bb-2d1974140ffd/iscsi-disk-not-available-for-storage?forum=winserverClustering

Comment: I already have KB2919355 installed.

Answer (score 1):

In failover cluster manager, go to your cluster-Storage-Disks . Right click the disk on the right pane and choose More actions-Turn on maintenance mode.

Comment: "Turn on maintenance mode" does not exist under "More Actions": https://imgur.com/a/nNMcW

Comment: I guess the reason is, that is your witness disk. You can assign another witness or temporarily remove it using "Configure Cluster Quorum Wizard" . If you have even number of nodes, don't forget to add a witness again.